# change bones position in a armature in blender game engine using python

Tags: python, game-engine, blender, kinect, blender-2.50

I am working on real time mapping of model with the user data obtained from Kinect.
I am able to get access to the individual bone using bge.types.BL_ArmatureObject().channels
which give the list of bones. I am not able to change the position bone. I tried to use rotation_euler to give it some rotation but it had no effect. Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a little late, but for blender >= 2.5 this should do the trick:

```
# Get the whole bge scene
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# Helper vars for convenience
source = scene.objects

# Get the whole Armature
main_arm = source.get('NAME OF YOUR ARMATURE')

main_arm.channels['NAME OF THE BONE YOU WANT TO ROTATE'].joint_rotation[ x, y ,z] # x,y,z = FLOAT VALUE

main_arm.update()
```

I also wrote this down in an extensive tutorial, starting here: http://www.warp1337.com/content/blender-robotics-part-1-introduction-and-modelling